# Error querying dbf file from network share using Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, oledb, 64-bit

Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 SP1,
Sql Server 2008 x64 SP3,
Access Database Engine x64 SP1

I have linked server:

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver @server = N'dbf2', @srvproduct=N'dbf2', @provider=N'MSDASQL', @provstr=N'DRIVER={Microsoft Access dBASE Driver (*.dbf, *.ndx, *.mdx)};'
```

When querying dbf file from local disk everything is OK:

```
select * from openquery(dbf2, 'select * from c:\\V4C8MA6.dbf') a
```

But when querying from network share

```
select * from openquery(dbf2, 'select * from \\\\gefest\\upload\\V4C8MA6.dbf') a
```

I've got the error:

```
Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
The OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "dbf2" reported an error. The provider did not give any information about the error.
Msg 7350, Level 16, State 2, Line 6
Cannot get the column information from OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "dbf2".
```

I've tried different variants to describe the path: [], "", ``, \"\", ....
Everything is OK with the nework share access, the sql server account has needded access rights. But...

How to make it work?

**Added on 04 may 2012:**

xp_cmdchell lists the directory perfectly.

This is what I discovered:
I created linked server with sprovstr indicating the location of the file:

```
@provstr=N'DRIVER={Microsoft Access dBASE Driver (*.dbf, *.ndx, *.mdx)};dbq=\\gefest\upload'
```

This works if I connect to the sql server using **sql server auth**.

This is what ProcMon shows when using **dbq**:

Date & Time:    5/4/2012 9:57:55 AM

Event Class:    File System

Operation:  CreateFile

Result: **SUCCESS**

Path:   \\gefest\upload\

TID:    8588

Duration:   0.0001988

Desired Access: Read Attributes

Disposition:    Open

Options:    Open Reparse Point

Attributes: n/a

ShareMode:  Read, Write, Delete

AllocationSize: n/a

OpenResult: Opened

This is when indicating **path in the query**:

Date & Time:    5/4/2012 9:58:53 AM

Event Class:    File System

Operation:  CreateFile

Result: **OBJECT PATH INVALID**

Path:   \\gefest\upload\

TID:    8588

Duration:   0.0000819

Desired Access: Read Attributes

Disposition:    Open

Options:    Open Reparse Point

Attributes: n/a

ShareMode:  Read, Write, Delete

AllocationSize: n/a

Why sql server receives desired access to the share at the first query and does not at the second?

The third and fourth variants are when connecting to the server using **windows auth**:

using **dbq**:

Date & Time:    5/4/2012 10:02:54 AM

Event Class:    File System

Operation:  CreateFile

Result: **ACCESS DENIED**

Path:   \\gefest\upload\

TID:    8588

Duration:   0.0031837

Desired Access: Read Attributes

Disposition:    Open

Options:    Open For Backup, Open Reparse Point

Attributes: n/a

ShareMode:  Read, Write, Delete

AllocationSize: n/a

**Impersonating:    GAZ\kozlovai**

indicating **path in the query**:

Date & Time:    5/4/2012 10:02:20 AM

Event Class:    File System

Operation:  CreateFile

Result: **OBJECT PATH INVALID**

Path:   \\gefest\upload\

TID:    8588

Duration:   0.0000378

Desired Access: Read Attributes

Disposition:    Open

Options:    Open For Backup, Open Reparse Point

Attributes: n/a

ShareMode:  Read, Write, Delete

AllocationSize: n/a

**Impersonating:    GAZ\kozlovai**

Sql server impersonates when connecting to the share. And this account 'GAZ\kozlovai' has full access to the share, but sql server still cannot open the file...

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if the user idenity under which the query runs has read and write access to the temp folder on the server. This is because SQL Server will create temp files for the query under the context of the calling user, not the SQLServer process account.

**EDIT**: I recall at least some instances of this problem arising only via UNC hosted shares, so it isn't a lead-pipe cinch it would happen on the local reference.

Just for grins, fire up an XP_CMDSHELL and perform a 'DIR \\SERVER\SHARE\FOLDER' and make certain you can talk to that path via UNC within SQL Server. If not, you still have an access issue to overcome.

Lastly, if all else fails, and you have login access to the server, I'd fire up a copy of Process Monitor and watch for network IO issues when that query fires.

Comment: Please loook at what I added on 04 may 2012.

Comment: Just read the extra information you posted, and something came to mind - as odd as this may sound, is there any chance your domain implements roaming profiles, and if any of the "standard" Windows folders are redirected to a network share?

Comment: One other thought - is the "upload" share on your "gefest" server mapped to the server's C:\ drive? Admittedly a longshot, but if so, you could be encountering restrictions on file activity in the root of the system drive across a network. As a test, you might move your .dbf file to a different folder, and create a secondary share for you to test your queries.